# Can I say "I just uploaded a joke/joking video to Youtube."?

Tags: word-choice

I tried to Google about `joking video` or `joke videos`. However, I couldn't find a lot of results. I guess it's because native speakers won't say "joke" or "joking" for such kind of video.

Actually the video is about me pretending to be a cat try to scare my teacher.

What adjective should I say in this sentence:

`I just uploaded a _______ video to Youtube.`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "humorous" would work best in that sentence. "Joking", "joke", "humor", "comic", or "comedic" could also modify "video", but they don't seem to work as well in this context.

A "joke video" could be one that includes jokes or that is made as a joke.

A "joking video" could mean a few different things, depending on whether "joking" is considered a present participle or a gerund. I won't go into the difference (because I think that that's getting a bit far from your question), but if you do some research on those concepts and the meaning still isn't clear, then feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! Especially the examples for each case!

Comment: Or "funny video"

Comment: @JamesK You're right, I think that that might work even better than my suggestion.